Assistance Needed for Configuring Raspberry Pi Compute module 4 as USB HID Mouse
Hello Raspberry Pi Community,
I am currently working on a project where I am trying to configure my Raspberry Pi (Compute Module 4) to act as a USB HID mouse for my PC. Despite following several tutorials and guides, I have encountered multiple issues that I cannot seem to resolve.
I can't find the link now but I found that someone managed to make it work using this tutorial.
Here are the details of my setup and the problems I’m facing:
Steps Taken:
USB Gadget Configuration:
I added "dtoverlay=dwc2" to /boot/config.txt.
I ran sudo modprobe libcomposite and sudo modprobe dwc2, rebooted and ran my setup.sh script.
My setup.sh script includes:
 set -e

sudo modprobe libcomposite
cd /sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/
mkdir -p g1
cd g1

# Set Vendor and Product IDs
echo 0x1d6b > idVendor  # Linux Foundation
echo 0x0104 > idProduct  # 

# Create string descriptors for serial number, manufacturer, and product
mkdir -p strings/0x409
echo "2" > strings/0x409/serialnumber
echo "Manufacturer" > strings/0x409/manufacturer
echo "Eye tracker" > strings/0x409/product

# Create configuration
mkdir -p configs/c.1/strings/0x409
echo "Config 1: HID Mouse" > configs/c.1/strings/0x409/configuration

# Set configuration attributes
echo 50 > configs/c.1/MaxPower  # Set Max Power in mA
echo 0xE0 > configs/c.1/bmAttributes  # bmAttributes: Self-powered, with remote wakeup.

# Create HID function
mkdir -p functions/hid.usb0
echo 2 > functions/hid.usb0/protocol   # Protocol 2: Mouse
echo 1 > functions/hid.usb0/subclass   # Subclass 1: Boot Interface
echo 3 > functions/hid.usb0/report_length  # Report length of 3

# Set HID report descriptor (example for a mouse)
echo -ne '\x05\x01\x09\x02\xa1\x01\x09\x01\xa1\x00\x05\x09\x19\x01\x29\x03\x15\x00\x25\x01\x95\x03\x75\x01\x81\x02\x95\x01\x75\x05\x81\x01\x05\x01\x09\x30\x09\x31\x15\x81\x25\x7f\x75\x08\x95\x02\x81\x06\xc0\xc0' > functions/hid.usb0/report_desc

# Link HID function to configuration
ln -s functions/hid.usb0 configs/c.1/

# Bind UDC to the gadget
echo "fe980000.usb" > UDC

# Set permissions for the HID device
chmod 777 /dev/hidg0

Current situation:
My PC now recognizes the Raspberry Pi as a USB Input Device, but it shows the status "This device cannot start. (Code 10)" along with a problem code indicating insufficient memory resources.
Power management settings on my PC do not allow the computer to turn off the device to save power.
More context: I managed to make the Raspberry Pi 4B to be seen as a mouse by a PC with a very similar script, but with CM4 I am having this issues.
Questions:
Could you please review my USB gadget setup and suggest any potential improvements or corrections?
What diagnostic steps should I take next to better understand the resource allocation issues?
I appreciate any assistance you can provide! Thank you for your time and support.

you seem to have ommited at least the line that outputs to functions/hid.usb0/report_desc - your last line is also quite different to the tutorial you apparently followed

In fact, disregarding the "informative" parameters (device name etc) - you seem to have omitted several lines from the tutorial, and drastically altered at least the report_length value (8 in the tutorial, 64 in your code) - it's like you were following a tutorial for something else

Thanks for the reply! I realized that I had pasted an old version of the code, now it is up to date! I understand that the report length can vary according to how complex we want the mouse to be. As I need only a simple implementation I left it in 3.

I managed to make the Raspberry Pi 4B to be seen as a mouse by a PC with a very similar script what are the differences? One of the differences is the issue - I suspect you need a report_length of 8
